# Generic.xaml doesn't use SystemParameters set in App.xaml

Tags: wpf, parameters, app.xaml, generic.xaml

To customize the look of `ScrollBar` I've set these:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">15</sys:Double>
```

in `App.xaml` and in the `Themes\Generic.xaml` some of my Custom Controls have `Grid.Column` defined like this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}"/>
```

Looks like my Custom Controls actually don't use `15` as `Width`. Is there any way to force Custom Controls Styles defined in `Themes\Generic.xaml` use these values set in `App.xaml`?

### EDIT

Here's what I've in `App.xaml` now:

```
<Application x:Class="RentManager.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RentManager"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
             xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:RentManager.CustomControl"
             xmlns:con="clr-namespace:RentManager.Common"
             StartupUri="Main.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">12</sys:Double>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">12</sys:Double>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/RentManager;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/RentManager;component/Themes/OtherStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The userControl on which I'm having issue looks like this when scrollbar appears:

[image]

Look at the Misalignment in the `Receivable/Payment` column. Here's how it looks without scrollbar:

[image]

The custom control for Ledger is:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Ledger}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Ledger}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                            <Separator Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Date" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Particulars"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Run Text="Receivable"/>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run Text="/ Payment"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Receipt"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Balance" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                            <Separator Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                                      ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Source}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="scroll">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.Template>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='dd MMM yyyy'}" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
                                        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1">
                                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTab.Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Ledger}}}" Value="Plot">
                                                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding SpaceName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=": "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding TenantName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" - "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding HeadName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" | "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding Narration}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </DataTrigger>

                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTab.Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Ledger}}}" Value="Space">
                                                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding PlotName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=": "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding TenantName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" - "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding HeadName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" | "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding Narration}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </DataTrigger>

                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTab.Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Ledger}}}" Value="Tenant">
                                                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding PlotName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=": "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding SpaceName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" - "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding HeadName}"/>
                                                                        <Run Text=" | "/>
                                                                        <Run Text="{Binding Narration}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ContentControl.Style>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                        <local:NumReport Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Receivable}" />
                                        <local:NumReport Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Receipt}" />
                                        <local:NumReport Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Balance}" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="5" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}">
                                            <Border.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=scroll}" Value="Visible">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Border.Style>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Separator Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Background="LightBlue" Margin="0 5 0 5"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                            <Separator Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Total" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>

                            <local:NumReport Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding TotalReceivable}"/>
                            <local:NumReport Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding TotalReceipt}"/>
                            <Separator Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Without these two lines:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">12</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">12</sys:Double>
```

in `App.xaml` it works as expected! Another thing is after Adding those MergedDictionaries in `App.xaml`, now I've red squiggles all over my `Generic.xaml`.

### EDIT

If I don't change those parameters in App.xaml, it looks as expected:

[image]

Comment: Adding the resource to `App.xaml` should work.

Comment: @mm8, after those two lines in App.xaml, added `<ResourceDictionary x:Key="n" Source="RentManager;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>`, doesn't work!

Comment: That's not how to merge a `ResourceDictionary`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I'm right or not, one actually can't change the constant `VerticalScrollBarWidth` or `HorizontalScrollBarHeight` (in my case Width and Height are always 17) BUT at run time these key values are used by the System to render application's scrollbar according to your desired width. So to get around the best way in my opinion is to declare a constant somewhere like this:

```
public const double ScrollBarThickness = 12;
```

and instead of setting these:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">12</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">12</sys:Double>
```

in `App.xaml` set those values in `App.xaml.cs` in this way:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    Resources.Add(SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey, Constants.ScrollBarThickness);
    Resources.Add(SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey, Constants.ScrollBarThickness);
}
```

and use that Constant in Binding wherever you need. In my case: I'd to redefine those two `Grid.Column` definitions and the dummy Border's Width in my Custom Control like this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static con:Constants.ScrollBarThickness}}"/>
<Border Grid.Column="5" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static con:Constants.ScrollBarThickness}}">
```

I actually don't need those Merging techniques at all, it works just fine without all those! I'd love to Bind the Constant in `App.xaml` as well BUT I do not know how to define Style for `VerticalScrollBarWidthKey` or `VerticalScrollBarWidthKey`. What would be the Property name (???):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">
     <Setter Property="???" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static con:Constants.ScrollBarThickness}}"/>
</Style>
```

if I wanted to Bind in `App.xaml` instead of `App.xaml.cs`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the resource to `App.xaml` does work.

Your way of referencing the `ResourceDictionary` is wrong though. You should merge it into `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/RentManager;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>


    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work! Do I have to reset anything in Build Action? Currently it's set as Page and `Custom Tool: MSBuild:Compile`.

Comment: The defaults will do just fine.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Are you actually using the system parameters in your custom styles? What does VS say about the squiggly lines?

Comment: Yes, in the Custom Control named `Ledger` I've posted. VS says different things If I hover over different lines  (eg. A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods, The name VM does not exist in cyrrent context, BooleanToVisibilityConverter could not be found, etc.)

Comment: Does it compile and run?

Comment: Even with those Red Squiggles it does compile and run. And If I just comment out those two `sys` lines in App.xaml, I don't have any alignment problem in that UserControl!

Comment: Alignment problem?

Comment: Yes, when the scrollbar appears it resizes the ItemsControl although I've a dummy border in the last column to account for ScrollBar width.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Your original question was how to change the values of the system parameters that are used in your style. I guess this has been answered/solved and the layout issue is a result of the new width and height?

Comment: I've three of these `<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}"/>` lines in my Custom Control defined in Generic.Xaml. But these Columns don't use 12 as column width.

Comment: Just commented out those two lines in App.xaml and added another snapshot of my app in last EDIT part of post. See that column doesn't have any alignment issue!

Comment: This means that my proposed solution works, doesn't it? The widths do change as expected based on the resources.

Comment: If you have another issue with your template that is not related to the original question of how to set the system parameters, you should ask another questions. This one should be closed as it has already been answered.

Comment: Without all those merging it worked and still works perfectly If I don't change the width of scrollbar. As soon as I add those two `<sys...` lines in App.xaml and follow all your instructions, it doesn't work, see those snapshots!

Comment: I'd set those Parameters beforehand BUT the problem is my custom controls doesn't care those parameters AND I asked to get a way to force the custom control. You told me to Merge those in App.xaml and I did accordingly BUT it still doesn't care those parameters, so those aren't yet set for Custom Styles. So In a nutshell, with or without merging it's same!

Comment: With the 16.6.1 update no more red squiggles BUT it still doesn't work! One more thing, In all of my UserControls, where I used Custom Controls,  I've a reference for Custom Controls folder like `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:RentManager.CustomControl" ` and I've used those controls like: `<cc:Card ..>.`, `<cc:TextField...>`, `<cc:PathButton...>`, etc..